# Active links in Ember based on property

Tags: ember.js, hyperlink

In Ember.js the [link-to](http://www.emberjs.com.cn/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_link-to) helper automatically sets an `active` css-class if the the current route matches the supplied routeName.

You could change that behaviour by applying the `current-when` argument, to set the `active` class if another route matches the supplied routeName.

But now I need to make the link active if a property is true. The only thing I could think about would be:

```
{{#link-to "subroute" current-when=aCPReturingTrueOrFalse}}
```

Obviously, this does not work, because the `current-when` argument does only supports strings. So how could I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After just thinking it little further through, it's actually quite simple. Just make an `inline-if-statement`:

```
{{#link-to "subroute" current-when=(if aCPReturingTrueOrFalse 'another-route' 'subroute')}}
```

---

In the future, setting a boolean value to the `current-when` argument should work though, see: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/14848.

**Edit**: Since [Ember 2.15](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v2.15.0), you can use a boolean value now!